# Add listener for all element events in WPF

Tags: wpf, events, hook, event-listener

I would like to hook for all available element events in one call. Some thing like this:

```
elem.AddHandler(AnyRoutedEvent, (RoutedEventHandler)handler)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this to get all events on the Button type... You can substitute a different type.

```
RoutedEvent[] events = EventManager.GetRoutedEventsForOwner(typeof(Button));

foreach (RoutedEvent e in events)
   elem.AddHandler(e, handler);
```

You can also substitute the following to get ALL routed events for ALL types, but that would be quite a list!

```
RoutedEvent[] events = EventManager.GetRoutedEvents();
```

Comment: Be careful of the leaks which this code might cause. Adding Event Handlers without removing them create leaks in WPF. You can see more information in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/2019.2/Inspections.html#event_handlers_leak

Answer (score 4):

You can use the RegisterClassHandler method of EventManager to staticly listen to all elements at once :)

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(your class), Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(OnButtonClick));

static void OnButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do awesome stuff with the button click
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this from inspiration from:http://geekswithblogs.net/tkokke/archive/2009/07/17/monitoring-routed-events-in-wpf.aspx

```
    /// <summary>
    /// This is used for debugging, when your looking for a specific event
    /// </summary>
    public static void RegisterAllEvents(Type type, FrameworkElement target)
    {
        var events = EventManager.GetRoutedEvents();
        foreach (var routedEvent in events)
        {
            EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(type,
                                routedEvent, new RoutedEventHandler((sender, args) =>
                {
                    if ( sender != target)
                        return;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(args.OriginalSource + "=>" + args.RoutedEvent);
                }));
        }
    }
```