# Is possible to log WPF application events(Mouse click, Drag, Drop, Selectionchanged) in a txt file

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I am developing a WPF application with code written in C#, My aim is to log all action that end user takes while using this application. Action could be a Mouse click, Drag, Drop, SelectionChanged etc. I want to log all such user interactions in the application UI, and have those actions stored as summarised one line descriptions of the action in a text log file.

Comment: Well,just add event handlers to all the actions you want to log and call from there to a common logging method

Comment: Thank you.. is this possible to achieve this globally. for example .Net framework provides an option to catch all unhandled errors or exception in common event called DispatcherUnhandledException. do we have any event like this for all triggered events in WPF instead of adding event handlers in all the actions.

Comment: I don't think there is one, and i can't think of why it would be useful. Have a look at this answer to see it it helps [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634434/add-listener-for-all-element-events-in-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Implement log4net with "EventLogAppender". It will log all your events to a single log file.
Refer for examples: https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html